# Safe force push procedure?

Tags: git, push, git-push

I hear that force pushing (`git push -f`) is a dangerous practice to be avoided if possible.  That being said, what would be a safe procedure for doing so in the case of a private repo shared among a small team?  I imagine it would be something like this:

1. I ask team members not to push until I'm done.
2. I fetch.
3. I update the branch's history as needed (amend, rebase, etc.).
4. I force push.
5. I tell them I'm done.
6. They do ___ to acquire and integrate the new history with their code without anything being lost.

Can someone complete this procedure or scrap it and offer a better one?  I'm looking for the simplest safe procedure.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "safe". If you're changing/removing code that has already been shipped to customers so that you now have no reproducability of that code, there is really no safe way to do it.

Comment: @Mort I'm trying to ask about the force-push aspect specifically though, as opposed to asking about rebasing in general.  To my knowledge, when you force push, you run the risk of overwriting someone else's push, leading to code getting lost or at least being difficult to recover.  I want to understand how to avoid that.  Maybe it would be adequate just to address the simplest case: that I want to amend my last commit but forgot to do so before I pushed and others pulled.

Answer (score 12):

You can do `git push --force-with-lease`
It will push your changes only when the remote branch is in the same state in the remote as you can see it locally.
See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---no-force-with-lease for more details.

Comment: `git push --force-with-lease` could be a helpful tool.  What overall procedure would it be a part of though?

Comment: Git provides light branches to use them often. Your work should be being done in a private branch which can be freely modified by you - preferably with `--force-with-lease`, to be on the safe side, when you need to force push. When working on a public branch I had to force push only once, when other developer forced pushed his work overwriting others commits. Then the whole team was asked to rebase their work if needed. When I forget to add a change to a public branch, I simply create a new commit. When I want to delete a change/commit from a public branch I do a revert commit.

Comment: Pushing forced uneccessarily engages the whole team to do an extra work risking commits loss.

Comment: I would recommand a dry run first: git push -n --force-with-lease

Answer (score 2):

The following approach looks kind of fragile but will work assuming all other team members don't have any local commits on the said branch.

You add code to the branch and push force it (steps 1-5 in your question):

```
git checkout feature
# Add code
git push --force-with-lease
```

Other developers on your team should do the following (Step 6):

```
git fetch
git branch -D feature
git checkout feature
```

After this has been executed, all team members will have the exact same branch as you.

**If any of them had any non-pushed commits, they will be lost!**

Answer (score 0):

Seems you understand what you're doing and why, and why it's unsafe. Let me add two points:

6. They do force-fetch/pull (`git fetch/pull -f`).
7. They verify carefully that any code they've already pushed didn't get lost. In case something is lost they use reference log (`git reflog`) to recover lost commits and cherry-pick/rebase them to the current branches.