# Rebase not behaving as expected

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a long series of commits which I'd like to remove from the history of my branch. I used git rebase -i

I then marked a number of commits with `fixup`, thinking they would be applied but without their commit message. I also marked some as `squash`, thinking they would be applied but that their commit message would be merged with the previous commit message. Some I left with `pick`, thinking they would stay as they are or have their following `squash` or `fixup` merged into them.

Once I'd marked them as I wanted, I typed `Esc` `:wq`, hit `return` and landed in the second editor screen. Here I simply hit `Esc` `:wq` and hit `return` again.

There were no problems reported so I typed `git push`. Git complained that I could not push without first pulling, so I typed `git pull`, then `git push`. This appeared to have satisfied the git gods but then looking at `git log` I see that the commit messages which I wanted squashed together are in face squashed into one message, unfortunately all the original commit messages are still in the log.

I was thinking they would be removed.

What have I done wrong and am I misunderstanding the process?
When I merge my branch into master will those `fixup`-ed commit messages get merged as well or will they disappear?

Comment: (WARNING don't do this hastily) I believe you want `git push --force` instead of `git pull`. That will overwrite **overwrite** the history of the remote branch. When you rebase, you by nature become out of sync with the remote repository.

Comment: That's sounds exactly what I want. Fortunately, the changes I've made are not difficult to redo, but I'd like to understand why the log appears to show commit messages which I thought would no longer be there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've pushed the previous history, your branch and the remote branch will have diverged from your rebase point. Running `git status` will show that your branch and the remote branch have diverged, which is why a push is not allowed:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F origin/feature
         \
          D'---E'---F' feature
```

When you issue a pull in this case, it will merge both versions of the history, so your old commits (from the remote) are still present as well as your new, rebased commits:

```
A---B---C----D----E----F origin/feature
         \              \
          D'---E'---F'---G feature
```

You *probably* want to `git push --force` and *completely rewrite that history*, but there are a number of risks with this: [Safe force push procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664456/safe-force-push-procedure)

If you do that, you will end up with this:

```
A---B---C---D'---E'---F' feature
                         origin/feature
```

Here, the old commits (`D-E-F`) are no longer part of your branch, and will be cleaned up later. (They *may* remain in the repo as part of other branches, or referenced by tags, but they will no longer appear in your history for the branch you're working on.)

Comment: So, it's safe as long as no-one else is pushing? That is the case, here.

Comment: Force push is usually difficult as it requires evaluating and rebasing all branches that might be affected (branches containing the old commits). If you are the only person working on this repo, this is safe but you will still need to think if other branches might be affected.

Comment: My questions remains somewhat: Will those commit messages be removed?

Comment: Yes, you're entirely overwriting that history in that branch, so D/E/F commits will no longer exist. (This is not quite true; if for example there is a tag that points to F, then the commits will still exist, but they're no longer part of your branch.)